# difficulty in understanding c pointers when it is on it's own

Tags: c, pointers

I am studying pointers for c and this placement of `*` really really confuses me.

I understand what `int *a` is..

But what is

```
a = malloc(n * sizeof(int) )
```

I understand what above is doing but why is `*` in the middle of by itself?? This part really confuse me so please someone can explain to me?

Comment: `*` multiplies `n` with `sizeof(int)`. It is the multiplication operator.

Comment: If more confusing would be the even better approach doing this: `int * a = malloc(n * sizeof * a) ;` ;-)

Comment: I thank you everyone.   I realize how silly this question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` here is very simple, and ironically, you'd have no problem figuring it out **before** you learned about pointers. Now, C's notoriously confusing syntax simply mislead you.

The `*` here is just multiplication. It's *n* times the size of *int*, which corresponds to an allocation of a block of memory capable of storing *n* *int*s

A simple way of telling the multiplication operator form the dereference operator is that multiplication should have **two operands** so `a = b * c` is clearly multiplication. While the dereference operator has a single operand like so: `a=*b` (`*` here works only on *b*).

Answer (score 5):

unary `*` means dereferencing and binary `*` means multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

The `*` in the middle is a multiplicative operator. The result of the binary `*` operator is the product of the operands.
Do not confuse it with unary dereference operator which applies only on pointer objects.

Answer (score 1):

`*` operator is used both for multiplication and dereferencing the pointer

```
int b=10;
int *a = &b;
```

`*a` is dereferencing the pointer, where `*` is a unary operator

```
int c = b * 10;
```

Here `*` does multiplication where `*` is a binary operator

Answer (score 0):

That's used to multiply values. `5*5` will produce 25. `int *a;` is a pointer to `a` while `a*a` is *multiply a by a*.

Answer (score 0):

Just to simplify. `*` when used before a variable (or etc) without any other variable (or etc) right before it, it's a unary operator, it just "affects" one single variable (or etc).  see the examples below:

```
int *a = 1
```

Another one:

```
a = b + *c
```

Notice that in the last example we have a variable before the `*` but not right before it, there's a plus sign(`+`) in the middle of them.

But if you have a variable (or etc) right before `*`, it's a binary operator, it "affects" two variables (or etc).

```
a = b * *c
```

See, here I'm using the two of them. I'm assigning the value of b times what c points to, to a.

Hope it helps you undestand it better.